# pkill -F doesn't work when invoked from a script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that terminates a process. The pid of the process is stored in a file called `foobar.pid`. BSD pkill has an option -F, which takes a pidfile and kills matching processes. Perfect!

So I have this line in my script:

```
pkill -F foobar.pid # doesn't work
```

But it doesn't work. If I manually enter the command, it works. What gives? Longer, but to my understanding equivalent, alternative that works in the script:

```
pid=$(cat foobar.pid)
kill $pid # works
```

Now that proves that the problem isn't:

- the script not being able to read the pidfile
- the script not being allowed to kill the process.

I've also tried changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, in case `sh` would've kicked some weird compatibility mode or something. No luck.

System specs:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Babar.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Full script:

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$(cat foobar.pid)
kill $pid # works
# pkill -F foobar.pid # doesn't work
rm foobar.pid
```

Comment: so did you read in the local systems man page for pkill that it accepts the `-F file` option, or did you read it someplace on the web?  AND does your script `cd` to the correct dir that contains the PIDfile? In any case, you have some perfectly good solutions, life is short, On to the next thing! Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yeah, the man page specifies the -F switch and it works when I type it in by myself, also the working directory is correct, evidenced by the $(cat foobar.pid) working. Thanks!

Comment: @shellter Having a workaround is not a solution, it is a workaroud lol
mjleino Did you already check if there is some bug report or issue open in pkill project?